# How join elements of numpy array into one string

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, join

How can I join elements of numpy array int one string element because i want to search in this data repetitive bits combinations?

```
img=cv2.imread("profile_default.jpg",0)
data = numpy.array(img)
img_str = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)[1]
img_str = numpy.array(img_str)


def decToBin(n):
    if n==0:
        return ''
    else:
        return decToBin(n//2) + str(n%2)


for i in range(0,img_str.size):
    byte=str(decToBin(img_str[i]))
    byte=byte.replace('[','')
    byte=byte.replace(']','')
    if byte == '':
        byte='00000000'
    if len(byte)!=8:
        zero_lacks=8-len(byte)
        for iterator in range(0,zero_lacks):
            byte= '0' + byte
    print(byte)
```

Comment: Does `np.unpackbits(img_str).astype('U1').view(f'U{img_str.size}').item(0)` do what you want?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, i just had to write {img_str.size*8} because new list of bits is 8 times longer

Comment: Yes, you are right, my bad. The totally correct form would be `{img_str.size*img_str.dtype.itemsize*8}` but in this case we can probably assume that it's one byte per item.